# Proof involving the Cauchy mean value theorem, Taylor series and induction.

Tags: calculus

I've been working on this problem for a long time and I'm stuck on it (nothing that I come up with is working). If someone could give me a hint or do the first part of the proof, that would be nice. The problem is,

Let $f(x)$ be a function on $[a,b]$ which is $(n+1)$ times differentiable at every point, for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $c$ be a point in $(a,b)$. Using induction and the generalized mean value theorem, prove that for any $x \in [a,b]$ \ $\left \{ c \right \}$,

$$\frac{f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^{k}}{\frac{(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}} = \frac{f^{(m)}(x_m) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\frac{f^{(m+k)}(c)}{k!}(x_m -c)^k}{\frac{(x_m -c)^{n+1-m}}{(n+1-m)!}}$$

For some $x_m$ that lies between $x$ and $c$ for $m=1,...,n+1$.